# Mapping density of variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my project I need to create two maps from my data frame in R

1.- A map with cases: I've created with "geom_density-2d".

2.- The same map, but instead cases on position, with values associates to that position (T_plz colum)

I'm not able to create the second map.

For map 1 this is the working code:

```
stagr <- c(left = -4.65162, bottom = 37.13429, right = -4.55350, top = 37.21455)
mapstagr_ter <- get_stamenmap(stagr, zoom = 13, maptype = "terrain")  


ggmap(mapstagr_ter) +
  geom_density2d(data = EH_GRA_B, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color = "navy", n = 150)
ggsave("2.3.3.-EH_DENS_GRA.jpeg")
```

But now I'm unable to create the map 2 with density of T_plz adapting the code ¿any idea?

Here a `dput()` for my data

```
dput(EH_GRA_B)
structure(list(T_plz = c(75L, 129L, 266L, 218L, 482L, 92L, 90L, 
78L, 69L, 21L, 40L, 47L, 28L, 58L, 206L, 72L, 69L, 112L, 62L, 
88L, 40L, 57L, 35L, 60L, 39L, 51L, 29L, 26L, 15L, 30L, 34L, 32L, 
20L, 16L, 45L, 78L, 68L, 30L, 29L, 22L, 46L, 62L, 149L, 215L, 
46L, 15L, 87L, 662L, 29L, 44L), longitude = c(-4.597636, -4.600515, 
-4.588572, -4.589938, -4.598265, -4.601427, -4.597413, -4.595821, 
-4.597891, -4.593336, -4.594576, -4.595756, -.588499, -4.601454, 
-4.983123, -4.133705, -4.48927, -4.486673, -4.488118, -4.488586, 
-4.487734, -4.598726, -4.601972, -4.487957, -4.513919, -4.600738, 
-4.485894, -4.602229, -4.602794, -4.596575, -4.597923, -4.600733, 
-4.602358, -4.598863, -4.651686, -4.488492, -4.487467, -4.517984, 
-4.416325, -4.59916, -3.765086, -4.173191, -4.487102, -4.609372, 
-4.744296, -4.532488, -4.488932, -4.399515, -4.738974, -4.692104
), latitude = c(37.177209, 37.172363, 37.169204, 37.174178, 37.173094, 
37.172678, 37.176522, 37.172593, 37.173501, 37.17338, 37.175979, 
37.176735, 37.176152, 37.174845, 37.018394, 37.299917, 36.918968, 
36.918124, 36.918553, 36.918838, 36.91834, 37.173858, 37.177105, 
36.917684, 36.743484, 37.174108, 36.917721, 37.176319, 37.177353, 
37.173081, 37.173507, 37.173443, 37.18146, 37.178015, 37.230832, 
36.918527, 36.91822, 36.745068, 36.701168, 37.175309, 37.493536, 
36.748598, 36.918034, 37.176214, 36.735513, 36.725117, 36.703989, 
37.095372, 36.735092, 36.736185)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Error: `could not find function "get_stamenmap"`

Comment: it is from the `ggmap` package, please install the package

Comment: @jammoyano, i believe the issue here is that the `T_plz` dont match with the `latitide` values. since it does not find those latitude it is not mapping

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the density of `T_plz`. The density of the measurements is already on your first plot. The variable `T_plz` is a measurement at each lat / lon point, and doesn't have a density as such. Are you looking for a contour showing the average value of `T_plz`

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, its a great definition "average value".
I've tried alternatively `geom_bin2d`, but I'm stuck at same point:
I'm able to create a heatmap with points (lat/long), but I'm unable to create a heatmap with sum 'T_plz' at each rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

I've been investigating about `geom_bin2d` and it's variant `geom_hex()` in a way to simplify the problem.

Those don't solve the problem and I was absolute sure this question has a existing function, so I keep investigating `ggplot`, and finally I get the right answer:

I've used `stat_summary_hex()` and this is what exactly need.

```
stat_summary_hex(data = EH_GRA_B, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, z = T_plz), bins = 50)
```

I've used the hexagonal variation of `stat_summary()` just to get a better visualisation.

Link to documentation:

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_summary_2d.html